# Install wxPython classic on OSX11.2 so I can run a project from source that imports wx

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to run a project from source that needs to import wx. I have tried more than one method.

1. I am getting the following error:

   > Can't find or import /pathToMyGitHubSources/wxWidgets/build/tools/build-wxwidgets.py, exiting.

   That is when I try installing from source using the following command:

   ```
   /usr/bin/python /pathToMyGitHubSources/wxPython/build-wxpython.py --build_dir=../bld --osx_cocoa
   ```

   I confirmed the file does not exist in the source folder:

   ```
   ls /pathToMyGitHubSources/wxWidgets/build/tools/
   appveyor.bat    msvs        release.bat release.sh  wxwidgets.iss
   ```

   I had pulled the sources from the following:

   - https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython.git
   - https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
2. I also tried installing a downloaded package using the following command:

   ```
   sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.2.0-cocoa-py2.7\ 1/wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.pkg -target /
   ```

   The package was downloaded from: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.2.0-cocoa-py2.7.dmg

   This only results in an error:

   > The Installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install
3. I installed a build using the following command:

   ```
   sudo -H pip install --upgrade --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
   ```

   However, this build, having the 'Phoenix' designation is apparently not compatible with projects that were made for the 'classic' builds. The wxversion() doesn't detect the install and even after a successful 'import wx', attempting to migrate the project using the [migration guide](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html) I found does not actually cover all of the differences I run into, such as

   > object has no attribute 'InsertColumnInfo'

   Error for the wx.ListCtrl objects. For this reason, I think I need to get classic wx installed. (If I continue trying the migration method, I'll make a separate question for it. )

Having failed my attempts at these three different methods, my question: **Is there a way to get wx classic installed, so that I may run the parent project from source?**

Comment: I just downloaded the dmg file, made sure my security settings were correct and double-clicked it. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, but this perhaps means you are using a different OS? Mine is OSX11.2 My security setting says "Allow apps downloaded from anywhere". Double-clicking gives me the same error as the command-line method I posted.

Comment: I was using Yosemite at the time, then I upgraded to El Capitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [change](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/changeset/f8f69118cd78869bd7e2dd1f1d7d1b6e8baae6fa/git-wxWidgets) was just pushed to source that restores the missing `build-wxwidgets.py`
Update to this version and then retry the `build-wxpython.py`.
After successful build, environment variables need to be set. Then wxversion fails to detect. Insert the path to wxPython* files at the beginning of the path list. Then finally able to import wx. Shown below.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx'
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=%DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=:'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx/lib'

python

import sys
import wxversion
try:
    wxversion.select(['3.0.3', '3.0'])
except wxversion.VersionError:
    print "wx version failed detection"
    sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

import wx
print wx.version()
```

Above wx is installed beginning by using method #1 in the question.

The package installer does not work with OSX 10.11 and over, so method #2 in the question doesn't work. Method #3 in the question leads to a lengthy migration process.